# What is mineral spirits called in Australia?

Tags: painting, polyurethane

I'm looking at cutting Polyurethane to use for a rub on finish, and the marvellous instruction articles and videos all say to do this with "mineral spirits". I am in Australia and unsure what this is.

Is it just mineral turpentine (turps), the same stuff that you use to clean up from oil based paints?

Is there any difference between normal turps and low odor turps for this purpose?

Or is mineral spirits what we call "white spirits" or dry cleaning fluid?

Hope someone can resolve this for me!

Comment: The best way to find out would be to ask at a local paint store, but I suggest paint thinner, turpentine, mineral spirits would all refer to the same or slightly different solvents in a group that would all work. However, "methylated spirits" would not work. Methylated spirits is ethanol (ethyl alcohol) which has been denatured with methyl alcohol and often also with pyridine to make it toxic and unpleasant to drink.

Comment: Apparently mineral spirits is actually methtylated spirits in Australia and New Zealand.

Answer (score 1):

Try shellite. I think that should work. By the way polyurethane is not meant to be rubbed on--normally brush or spray. If you really want products to be rubbed on try a French polish supplier.

Answer (score 1):

> White spirit (UK & Ireland)[note 1] or mineral spirits (US, Canada), also known as mineral turpentine (AU/NZ), turpentine substitute, and petroleum spirits

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_spirit)

Answer (score 0):

mineral turpentine - white spirit in UK

Answer (score -1):

In the US "mineral spirits" are naptha  , as in varnish and paint makers naptha ( somehow identified as V M & P) . It is similar to gasoline with low odor and no octane, etc. requirements. It could be called "paint thinner" but that name does not seem to be very specific. Absolutely nothing to do with turpentine or typical chlorinated cleaner fluids ( eg. chloroethane).